# FastAPI 307 just in deploy

Tags: python, deployment, fastapi

I'm trying to deploy my FastAPI app in render.com, it is working normally locally, but when I deploy, it returns:

- Calling endpoint local:

  http://localhost:8000/movie_predict?movie_name=Shrek
  Status 200
- Calling endpoint render.com:

  https://example-url-not-real/movie_predict?movie_name=Shrek Status 307

Render.com terminal response:

> Sep 24 12:24:02 PM  INFO:     189.6.6.250:0 - "GET /movie_predict?movie_name=Shrek HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect

I tried the snippet in this issue: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2060#. But then my React app can't access because there is no CORS config. Anyone have a tip?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from recSys.recommendationSystem import simple_movie_recommendation, aggregated_movie_recomendation, data
from traceback import print_exception
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(

    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["POST", "GET"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    expose_headers=["*"]
)

@app.get("/movie_predict/")
async def simple_recommendation(movie_name: str = Query(..., description="Name of the movie")):
    try:
        movies_list = simple_movie_recommendation(movie_name)

        return JSONResponse(
            status_code=200,
            content={'movies': movies_list},
        )

    except Exception as e:
        print_exception(e)
        return JSONResponse(
            content={'message': 'Internal server error'},
            status_code=500
        )
```

Comment: `307` is usually caused by you registering `/movie_predict/` with a slash at the end, but accessing `/movie_predict` (without the slash), making Starlette/FastAPI issue a 307 redirect so the URL matches.

Comment: @MatsLindh have you have an example how to do this? Or it just remove the last slash? I'm learning how to use FastAPI yet

Comment: It has nothing to do with Fastapi. Its because of the the trailing slash. Read more [here](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/php/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url.html)

Comment: Now it's just returning 502 Bad Gateway, but just in render.com, locally it is working normal...